# How can i improve the query performance for varchar(400) when trying to find one record in 5.4 million

Tags: c#, mysql, database, web-crawler

I’m in the process of writing WebCrawler, which will get all the local site links on one particular website.  The process is to identify which links are products and feed them into my price comparison software.

The problem I’m finding, is that I have now got an incomplete crawl of the site standing at 5.4 million links.   When running at those numbers, storing the collected links in memory in hashset and then saving them out into flat text file is probative.    The hashset is blowing memory consumption and I only have around 5gigs of operating memory.

Each time I acquire a new link, I need to check whether it has been captured before.    Hence hashset seemed the fastest way to do this comparison.
With the memory issues, and my text files topping 1.5gigs in size,  I thought it would be better to switch to the database – MySQL56.   Which I’m running on window 7 64bit, in developer mode.

I have migrated all the data captured in mysql56 database, using “LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE”,  this seems to worked well, but the URL column Is just a varchar(400).

The problem I’m having now, is a query to see if the url is present in the table is taking around 10-15 seconds.  Is there any way I can dramatically improve this performance.

One note that I did try was setting field to unique(with a smaller field limit), but in doing so, the database seemed to be unresponsive when doing the load data in file with 5.4 million records.

I’m currently developing in c#, using SQLconnector.

What I would like to know is, can I improve the performance of this text field,  are there any alternative ways for storing and querying this data.

Thanks

Comment: slap an index on the field

Comment: Can I do that after the fact when the database is already in the table?  Would that be adding unique index, as per SQLworkbenche's description?

Comment: a unique index would require ALL of the urls to be unique. if you've got any dupes, the index will fail to be created. but yes, you can add indexes after-the-fact. It'll take a while to create it, since it'll be running through ALL the records to index them, but it should help with select queries down the road.

Comment: Make sure your db is [normalized](http://www.cpcstech.com/pdf/simple-guide-to-five-normal-forms-in-relational-database-theory.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could look into using partitions with your table structure in MySQL. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-types.html

you mentioned trying to store all data in memory, but it was too much. you could put a memory cache in front of your database to gain some of the performance. memcached or I think MySQL has one of its own now.

Comment: +1 Memcached or similar technology can be quite appropriate here indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You got couple options:

1. First and foremost, put an index on the field.  The reason it takes 10-15 seconds is because it is likely doing a table scan rather than an index scan.  You can check that by looking at execution plan.  It doesn't have to be unique index (unless you want DB to reject insert of same value).
2. Another thing you can do will help with table search as well as with memory pressure.  Instead of holding entire URLs in memory that can be quite lengthy, compute MD5 (or any other hashing function) of every URL, and store that in memory.  Similarly, ain DB, along with URL, store the MD5 signature of the URL, and then search by that value (also indexed).  This way it'll need to compare far less bytes, and thus will be faster.
3. Combine your DB and memory approaches by having limited cache in memory, and full store in DB.  In memory, keep MD5 keys and how old they are (time, or FIFO, or distance from your current page in website's link graph).  When you need to check the link, check your memory cache.  If a hit, then you know you visited the url.  If cache miss, only then go to database to really see if has been visited.  This will hopefully reduce number of database queries you need to do (depends really how often links repeat themselves).

Other things to consider for optimizations:
 1. Some sites have redundant links that appear different but for your purpose are the same. Examples would be printable versions, mobile version, feedback view vs price view, etc.  You may want to study site's url structures to know which ones are interesting to you and which are not.  Discard the latter ones from your memory/db.
 2. Some sites don't really have links as in anchor tags, and instead use JavaScript event handling to figure out if something is clickable and how to process it (e.g. jQuery's selectors).  You may be missing parts of site if it employs such techniques.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps loads, I'm using much of the techniques described, but I like the idea about calculating my own MD5 checksum.   Since moving over to the database, I'm no longer storing all the URLS in memory, I'm totally relying the query to the database for each URL.  Is this practical seeing that I want to be querying 1000s urls min.

Comment: Databases are pretty powerful these days and can handle the load, but it depends on the database, and tuning those is an art in itself.  Are you saying you'll be making 1000s queries per minute?  If that makes your DB stumble, then consider some sort of sharding to distribute the load among more than one db (using MD5 for example as determinant for which DB URL goes into).

Comment: Also, just occurred to me that you may be able to reduce the number of queries by using limited local cache and DB combination.  I'll update answer in a second.

Comment: Question,  I've not generated MD5 keys before - can you point to good algorithm that I can can implement them in c#.   Also isn't there a limited chance that I could get key collisions, i.e. two URLS generating the same key.  Therefore prematurely discarding URL?   Also - last question (sorry I'm relatively new to databases), isn't creating an index on url column effectively the same as generating a lookup of MD5 keys as column in database.   Sorry if I'm missing something and thankyou for the help.

Comment: @GregoryWilliamBryant For MD5, you'd want to use [`MD5CryptoServiceProvider` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) (example in the linky).  Yes there is a very very small probability of hash collision, but I don't think this is something you'd need to worry for your application.  You can look into SHA512 to further lower the probability (I believe that would, not 100% sure), but I think that's an overkill for your application. Since hash is smaller in size, it should cause less internal IO and thus be faster lookup.

Comment: @GregoryWilliamBryant Clarification to previous comment: You should store hashes in db in binary form, not in text form, so it will be half the size, and comparison would be bit-wise comparison.

Comment: Thankyou LB2,  I'll look into all of this and get back you you with how I got on.

Comment: I've implemented these changes, now querying the table using the following query "SELECT * FROM captured_urls WHERE url_md5= UNHEX('2eda2cd5ce298a837ffce99b5fc45f7e');"  is taking between 8 and 12 seconds.   Does that sound reasonable, or is there sever side setting I need to tweak.   This detabase is running on local machine, with 6gigs memory and regular hard disk.

Comment: @GregoryWilliamBryant Do you have an index over `url_md5` column?  What does the query plan say about how it runs the query?  (you may need to get someone who's proficient with MySQL to figure out if that's the best the query can do)...

Comment: if I do an explain, I get this  - '1', 'SIMPLE', 'captured_urls', 'index', NULL, 'PRIMARY', '24', NULL, '6173879', 'Using where; Using index'.   I have url_md5 as a primary key, would that be safe to conclude that it's indexed.

Comment: @GregoryWilliamBryant Sorry, at this point I'd have to turn it over to someone who's intimate with MySQL.  MySQL performance is beyond my knowledge... :(

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback,   I've just slapped a partition on it, and its made dramatic improvement.   Much appreciate all the suggestions - seems like both answers have helped.